# Game Center InviteFailed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center, multiplayer

I'm am attempting to send a Game Center invitation. Sending from the simulator to a device or from a device to the simulator results in an InviteFailed error.

What might be the problem? Incorrect implementation? Low Internet speed? Or is it not possible to test Game Center invites with the simulator?

Thanks
[image: Invite Failed]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how it's failing? Is there console output?

Comment: In MatchMakerViewController in the field, where player can invite other player there is silmply written (Invite Failed)

Comment: Were you able to test invites on a dev enviroment (Sandbox) with two devices? I know it doesn't work on the simulator, but it's not working for me on the devices either.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only one iPhone, so I did not tested this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I am aware you cannot test multiplayer in the simulator. You will need two devices.

Answer (score 7):

Even though the invite functionality doesn't work in the simulator, you can still test multiplayer in the simulator using findMatchForRequest (kind of like an auto-match function):

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *match, NSError *error)
```